# Select specific rows

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting in Microsoft Word to copy rows one and three.

```
    Dim Myrange as Range
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set.myrange= .Rows(1,3) .Range
    myrange.End= .Rows(1,3) .Range.End
    End With
    Selection.Copy
```

This gives the error of wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code that you tried rather than posting it in comment where it looks all jumbled up? Once you do that, delete the above comment.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? what is the `.` doing between `Set.myrange` and a space between `.Rows(1,3) .Range`?

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do, but everything inside the `With` block is wrong.

Comment: Assuming this is for MS-Word... I will add the corresponding tag.

Comment: I'm trying to create a macro to copy a table, but only copy rows 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

To copy rows 1 and 3, you have to copy row 1 first and then copy row 3

To copy Row 1, use this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myrange As Range
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        Set myrange = .Rows(1).Range
        myrange.End = .Rows(1).Range.End
        myrange.Copy
    End With
End Sub
```

Similarly do it for 3 once you have pasted the copied row somewhere...

Comment: That didn't work for what I want to do. The macro needs to copy row 3 and row one onto the clipboard with clicking a command button, so that the user of the form can paste that info into another document.

Comment: AFAIK (and I could be wrong), You have to copy them separately. Had it been rows 1 TO 3 then it would have been a different case.

Comment: There isn't any type of exclusion argument that could be put in?

Comment: Perhaps a way to make the second line hidden from printing?

Comment: You could delete the 2nd row and then copy and then in the end close the document without saving?

Comment: That could work! How could the code then be written to delete the second row first, copy the table to the clipboard, then restore the 2nd row?